# how to use Scope variable base on index?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

In `AngularJS`, one scope variable is assigned to `ng-repeat`. I have multiple `div` with click `event function`. When I click on the first `div`,  its data is displayed with `ng-repeat`using the `mydatalist` scope variable. After this, if I click on another `div` same function is called and same scope variable is initialized with different `data.display` in this second `div`. The effect and the data of the first `div` are removed, and the second `div` data is filled.

I want that both data are different. How can I manage different scope variables with ng-repeat?

Comment: We feel the best Stack Overflow questions have a **bit of source code** in them.

Answer (score 1):

The approach is easy, you only need to use a different scope variable for each `div`. In the function that opens your `data list` items, you need to create a copy of your `mydatalist` variable instead of using it. Check the next snippet and it surely gives you an idea to solve your issue:

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller("myController", ["$scope", function($scope) {

  var mydatalist = ["Subitem 1", "Subitem 2", "Subitem 3"];

  $scope.datos = [
    {value: "Item 1", items: []},
    {value: "Item 2", items: []},
    {value: "Item 3", items: []},
    {value: "Item 4", items: []},
    {value: "Item 5", items: []}
  ];

  $scope.openItem = function(item) {

    if (item.open) {

      item.items = [];

    } else {

      item.items = angular.copy(mydatalist);

    }

    item.open = !item.open;

  };

}]);
```

```css
.item {
  background: #FFF;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  font: normal 14px Arial;
  line-height: 25px;
  text-indent: 10px;
}

.item:nth-last-child(n + 2) {
  border-bottom: none;
}

.subitem {
  background: #EEE;
  border-top: 1px solid #CCC;
  line-height: 25px;
  text-indent: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myController">
    <div ng-repeat="item in datos" class="item">
      <div ng-click="openItem(item)">{{item.value}} ({{item.open ? "open" : "close"}})</div>
      <div ng-show="item.items.length > 0">
        <div ng-repeat="subitem in item.items" class="subitem">
          {{subitem}}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```